# If a category has pullbacks and a terminal object, then it has (binary) products

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$
The questions is in the title.

Here is what I have attempted.  I want to know if this is enough.

Let $1$ be the terminal object in a category $K$.
Given objects $X, Y$ consider the pullback diagram:

$$\begin{CD}
P @>p_{1}>> X \\
@Vp_{2}VV @VVV\\
Y @>>>1\\
\end{CD}$$

therefore we have the product cone:

$$\begin{CD}
P @>p_{1}>> X \\
@Vp_{2}VV \\
Y
\end{CD}$$

Consider the product cone :

$$\begin{CD}
A\times B @>\pi_{A}>> A\\
@V\pi_{B}VV \\
B
\end{CD}$$

$$\begin{CD}
X @>f>>A\\
@V g VV\\
B
\end{CD}$$

then $$X  \xrightarrow[g]{f}   A \times B$$

is the unique factorization through the product.
is that enough?

Answer (score 1):

You gave the idea, but you have of course to show that the pullback is a product. That is given an object $A$ and morphisms $\xi\colon A \to X$ and $\eta\colon A \to Y$ that there is a unique morphism $(\xi,\eta) \colon A \to P$ such that $\xi = p_1 \circ (\xi,\eta)$ and $\eta = p_2 \circ (\xi, \eta)$. For doing so you can use the properties of the pullback ...

Comment: I expanded on my answer is that sufficient?